# Session variable has old value, needs to update with page redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have session variable that dont update with new value. I have two pages, one were you enter the values and klick on the button and you get redirected to page 2 and there you can check your input, if this is wrong you click back-button and you go back to the first page where you can change the input but now when i click the button to validate again the new value does not show up in the session variable but only the old value. I have been readingabout session for the last day but i just cant find the problem, the behind code is below:

Page1

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Session["value1"] != null)
    {
        lbl1.Text = (String)this.Session["value1"].ToString();
    }
}   

public string info { get { return lbl1.Text; } }

protected void inputButton_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();

    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        Session["value1"] = info;

        Response.Redirect("~/validpage.aspx");
    }

}
```

Page 2

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["value1"] != null)
    {   
        lbl2.Text = (String)Session["value1"].ToString();
    }        
}

protected void BackButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["value1"] = lbl2.Text;

    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
}
```

Maybe i have staired my self blind on this code as to me this should not have this problem it is presenting. Any idea and help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you set the session value at all in `BackButton_Click`?

Comment: So if you typed foo in the first screen, clicked `inputButton`, foo shows up in lbl2 on page 2, but if you typed bar on page 2, and clicked 'BackButton' foo still shows in page 1?

Comment: In Page 1 this `lbl1` is a label or textbox and where do you change your session value ?

Comment: Goog question Tim, guess i can change that as it should not need to be. Page 2 only displays values and dont let user change them therefor user has to go back to page 1 to alter the input. its a textbox on page1 and a label on page 2. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @user1501127 still if you can change value in `Page1` it should show updated value `lbl1.Text` is it Textbox ?

Comment: In page 1 when button_clicked i set the value to session if the page is valid. Page 1 has a textbox and Page 2 the label and if the user wants to change wat is displayed on page 2 he clicks back and gets redirected to page 1 with the textbox displaying the value and user can change it, up to this everything works but if the user changes the values and clicks again for page 2 the label on page 2 displays the old value and not what the user updated it too. Is the page refreshing somewhere i dont relize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time Page1 loads, lbl1 is set to the contents of the session, unless it's never been set. So when you click the button, the lbl1 is first set back to the content of the session as the page is loaded. You then read this value back & but it back in the session.

try this instead:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostback)
    {
        if (this.Session["value1"] != null)
        {
            lbl1.Text = (String)this.Session["value1"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This says only set the value if we're not postback, ie NOT clicking a button on the page.

Also in page2, there's no need to call ToString AND cast to a string. Do either, not both.

Comment: Thanks Simon! This solved the problem, now i just need to sort all the rest ;) Have a good one!